# How to list media files in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I want to list down all media files available in internal or external storage using Xamarin Forms Portable class library. How is it possible?

I am using Dependency Injection Service.

Code used for getting files :

```
public List<string> GetFiles()
{
    var files = new List<string>();
    var documentsPath = Android.OS.Environment.RootDirectory;
    var list = documentsPath.ListFiles();
    if (list.Count() > 0)
        foreach (var file in list)
        {
            files.Add(file.Name);
        }
    return files;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of need, a good reflex is to check Xamarin Cross Platform plugins of community here: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents

Take a look at FileStorage/FileSystem, FilePicker plugins

Comment: How can I implement this? Is there any document or blog available for that?

Comment: Each plugin is documented directly on Github.